# React native trouble calling function within another function?

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, firebase, react-native

in my React-native app I am trying to call another function within my `listenForItems` function, but keep getting the error `this.populateArray is not a function. In 'this.populateArray(solutions)', this.populateArray is undefined.` I do this in other classes and it's working, but for some reason it's not working here. Is there anything I'm missing?

```
populateArray: function(solutions) {
    var completed = [];
    var inProgress;

    for (var i = 0; i < solutions.length; i++ ) {
        if (solutions[i].completed == 0) {
            inProgress = solutions[i].id;
        }
        else {
            completed.push(solutions[i].id);
        }
    }
},  

listenForItems: function(cluesRef) {

    var solutions = [];
    userSolutionsRef.orderByChild('user_id').startAt(0).endAt(0).once('value', function(snap){
        var solution = snap.val();
        for (var i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
            if (solution[0].hunt_id == 0) {
                solutions.push(solution[0]);
            }
        }
        this.populateArray(solutions);
    });
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic this scope issue of javascript. Google will help with better understanding. In short, the word "this" inside a function refers to that function. In this example it refers the anonymous function (callback) that you use in userSolutionsRef.orderByChild. There are many ways to solve this. You can use ES6(ES2015) arrow functions in which case it becomes something like

```
userSolutionsRef.orderByChild('user_id').startAt(0).endAt(0).once('value', (snap) => {
    var solution = snap.val();
    for (var i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
        if (solution[0].hunt_id == 0) {
            solutions.push(solution[0]);
        }
    }
    this.populateArray(solutions);
});
```

or es5 solution

```
var that = this;
userSolutionsRef.orderByChild('user_id').startAt(0).endAt(0).once('value', function(snap){
        var solution = snap.val();
        for (var i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
            if (solution[0].hunt_id == 0) {
                solutions.push(solution[0]);
            }
        }
        that.populateArray(solutions);
    });
```